# make custom annotation view (callout view) with own button

Tags: iphone, dictionary, annotations, callout

Hey I followed this tutorial
http://www.codigator.com/tutorials/advanced-mapkit-tutorial-for-ios-custom-callout
and it works partly. But I cannot link the button. 
I would like to come to the next view, if I click on the annotation view. I have added a lot of buttons to the view, but none of them works and mostly the app crashes.

Could you help me... thanks.

Comment: yes really strange issue, but if you will choose color overlay in top menu of your simulator you will check that the area of your CalloutView view is red. it means you can't press here on any buttons or interact with them.

Comment: sorry but I don't really understand what you mean. I habe my own annotation view with a button. How can I connect it to an action?

Comment: I am not sure about this tutorial, because there is CalloutView is outside of tapped frame. Go to the debug and choose color overlay when CalloutView is shown, you will see interaction area or area without interaction (in the red color). is there way to implement rightCalloutAccessoryView by default? if yes I will share you code

Comment: ok i see it isn't such a good tutorial. Maybe you have a better one. It would be really great, cause I try it for days and come to no solution.

Comment: does anyone have an idea???????